# Why my rich cards are shown in Structured Data section?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-rich-snippets

I recently added Rich Cards to my shop project. But in Google Console they are in the "Structured Data" section. And my product Structured Data is getting doubled. And my "Rich Cards" section is empty too.

[image: console image]

[image: rich cards]

Should I remove structured data or both of them work well with each other?

**Rich Cards code:**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "LG K10- K430DS Dual SIM - 4G Mobile Phone",
    "alternateName": "گوشی موبایل ال جی کا 10-کا430 دی اس  دوسیم کارت- 4G",
    "image": "http://___.com/Files/ProductImages/ال-جی-کا-10-کا430-دی-اس-دوسیم-کارت-4G_9471.jpg",
    "description": "فروش آنلاین و بررسی تخصصی گوشی موبایل ال جی کا 10-کا430 دی اس  دوسیم کارت- 4G در فروشگاه اینترنتی دنیای دیجیتال",
    "brand": {
    "@type": "Thing",
    "name": "LG",
    "alternateName": "ال جی"
    },
    "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "worstRating": "0",
    "bestRating": "5",
    "ratingValue": "3.6",
    "reviewCount": "5"
    },
    "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "priceCurrency": "IRR",
    "price": "5480000.00",
    "priceValidUntil": "6/6/2017 6:11:58 PM",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",

    "seller": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "فروشگاه اینترنتی دنیای دیجیتال"
    }
    }
    }
</script>
```

**Structured data code:**

```
<div class="product-details-box" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="">
    <span class="title-fa" itemprop="alternateName">گوشی موبایل ال جی کا 10-کا430 دی اس  دوسیم کارت- 4G</span>
        <span class="title-en" itemprop="name">LG K10- K430DS Dual SIM - 4G Mobile Phone</span>
...
</div>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich cards are currently only being used for Recipes and Movies at present: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/05/introducing-rich-cards.html?m=1

It also looks like you are returning the exact same information in both bits of code - Product information. It's just one is in JSON-LD format and one is in embedded Microdata. So yes you are duplicating your own efforts here. Pick one format. Google is favouring JSON-LD at the moment (your top one) though doesn't yet accept every type of rich snipped in that format.